# finding all iframe srcs with jquery

Tags: jquery

is there a way, with jquery, to for exapmle on click, find all iframe elements, remove their src= tag, and give it back? sort of, refresh :)

Was looking for foreach function or something like that, but I'M rather hopeless at this :(

Thanks for your time,
Mart

Comment: If refreshing is what you want? Check my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#somebuttonid').click(function() {
        $("iframe").each(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', src);  
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: That would give each `iframe` the `src` of the first `iframe`.

Comment: @Jannis: It's being reset to itself, though. I think this is the correct interpretation of "remove and give back; sort of refresh". (requiring adjustment according to Felix's comment, of course)

Answer (score 3):

You can refresh all the iframe like this

```
$("iframe").each(function() { 
   $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src')); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to [`.attr()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) (or [`.prop()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)):

```
$('iframe').attr('src', function(index, val) {
    return val;
});
```

This function is executed for each element. It's a bit more concise than using an explicit `.each` loop.

Comment: Please explain the downvote so that I can improve my answer. Thank you!

Comment: How did this answer `remove their src= tag, and give it back`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need jQuery:

```
for(var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
   frames[i].src = frames[i].src;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful. Now let's find all typos at this site and downvote them all @LuisTellez

Comment: I was not able to edit it since I need to change at least 6 chars, thats the only reason why I pointed it out.